# How to translate: "Keep/leave something". So, how to express intention to leave something unchanged

Tags: grammar, usage, translation

Consider questions like:

```
Please leave the door open, thanks!

Could you please keep the lift's doors open? Thankyou

Please, leave it as it is.
```

They all imply something common: not changing the state of something. I know that `まま` is involved in this situations.

For example, this sentence is translated in this way:

```
そのままにして下{くだ}さい => Please, leave it as it is
```

And I know it is correct as I used it when I lived in Japan. But I do not know how to express more complex situations, like those ones I mentioned before.

Could you also provide a generic explanation, I mean the grammar rules behind this? Thankyou!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is ~て+おく, e.g.

> そのままにしておいてください。
>   Please leave it the way it is.

The rationale is you do something and then you leave it that way ([置]{お}く means to put/leave). In informal situations ~て+おく is oftened shortened to ~とく, e.g.

> ドアを開けといてください。
>   Please leave the door open. (*lit.* Please open the door and leave it that way.)

Similar constructions are

- ~てみる "to try to do sth.", or
- ~てしまう "to do sth. (with a negative connotation)"

Comment: Any comments, criticism, suggestions from the downvoter?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think ~ておく is only appropriate when the agent performs the action, and not when the state is simply allowed to persist.

Comment: Do not know who downvoted it, I think it is really useful answer. Actually I wanted some clarifications.
1) You said the short form is 〜とく, so, is this example correct? 荷物はどこに置いたらいいですか。ああ、あそこに置いとくね。 Is it correct? Can I say あそこに置いとけ下さい。?
2) 〜てしまう can also mean something done and finished right?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Your first example is correct. For your second example, you need to regard ~とく as normal verb, so you would need its ~て form to go before ください, i.e. あそこに置いといて下さい. 2) That depends on the tense you use: ~てしまう is non-past tense and can refer to something that's not done and finished. ~てしまった is past tense and done and finished, e.g. 食べてしまった "Sorry, I just ate it." (which, by the way, is often shortened to 食べちゃった, i.e. ~てしまう is shortened to ~ちゃう).

Answer (score 7):

`〜ておく` means to do something in advance as preparation/expectation for something happening.  That is to say, the thing is not yet done.

> - パーティーのため、ケーキを作っておく。　→　I'll make a cake (ahead of time) for the party.

However, if the action is already done and you want it to continue to remain in that state, use `〜たまま`.

> - ドアを開けたままにしてください。　→　Please leave the door open (as it was already open). / "Please let the door remain as opened."
> - (Facebook login in Japanese) ログインしたままにする　→　Keep me logged in.

Comment: Really appreciated the example of the Facebook login, nice!

Comment: Between yours and user1205935 answer, I chose the latter because it is little more complete. I really liked the short form explained in that answer, that's all. It is a detail, really, both answers are very good, but I had to choose... Thanks a lot istrasci!

Comment: No problem, you're free to choose whichever helped you more.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, another way might be to use `〜っ放{ぱな}し` on the end of the `連用形` (conjunctive form) of verbs, but in contrast to `〜たまま` it tends to have a negative nuance, e.g. `ドアを開けっ放しにしないでください` "Please don't leave the door open".

Comment: It is really interesting this other way you proposed. Since I studied Japanese in a pattern-fancy way, could you please explain what is the conjunctive form? Could you also detail a little more, the usage of っ放{ぱな}し? Thankyou

Comment: @Andry the `連用形{れんようけい}` form of a verb is used before e.g. the `〜ます` form (for example as in `走り（ます）` and `食べ（ます）` etc), there's a table at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Japanese_verbs). I'll try to expand on my answer a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

How about using 放る　as in 放っておく.

[まま　と　放る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9368/769)